# Differences of: SoftwareCenter history, dpkg-query and /var/log/dpkg.log.*?

Tags: apt, software-center, package-management, dpkg

I have just again run across the problem "find out which packages I installed some certain days ago". I have read several Q&A on askubuntu and there are always different ways suggested to do this:

- use the **history** in the **Software Center**
- use `dpkg-query -l`  (though I cannot seem to find any info on the install-date there
- browse through `/var/log/dpkg.log`
- (not to forget) the **history** in Synaptic Package Manager

My question is: Am I correctly assuming that the information received is not always the same. For instance it appears to me that the **history** solutions of Software-Center and Synaptic Package manager are only showing packages that they have handled "themselves". This means they omnit all those packages installed/removed/upgraded via the command line (i.e. via `dkpg` or `apt-get`).

Can somebody help me out and (a) confirm that there is a difference and (b) maybe point out the differences to me. Most interesting there is also the question if "installation date/time recordings" are only available via the browse `/var/log/dpkg.log.*` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, the Ubuntu Software Manager and Synaptic track the package changes in their own log files, but that means that if you don't use these programs *all the time* the log will be incomplete and you will have problems trying to verify this.

I didn't found in the manual for `dpkg-query` any clue that it provided the *installed date*, but `dpkg-query -l` indeed prints the general status of the packages, version, architecture and description.

So, who is more trustable? Obviously, all the *package manager* are in last instance frontends to `dpkg` who is the one that takes the actions of installation, configuration and deletion, and it's log is in `/var/log/dpkg.log*`. Now lets programmatically answer your questions:

> Am I correctly assuming that the information received is not always the same?

As I said above, yes. The programs are not running at every given time, and shouldn't be, hence they could ever keep track of every package change.

> Can somebody help me out and (a) confirm that there are a difference and (b) maybe point out the differences to me?

Yes, and the differences are above said.

> Most interesting there is also the question if "installation date/time recordings" are only available via the browse /var/log/dpkg.log.* method?

If you have a correctly set clock and used `apt-get`, obviously both logs, apt-get's and dpkg's, will log the same at the same time, with the same time. If you use `apt-get` all the time is understandable that you could read either log and have the same information. So, no, *installation date and time recordings* are available whatever logs you check (unless the logs are set to not print time), but dpkg's will always be more complete.

Comment: Thank you for confirming most of my initial thoughts. I'm grateful you checked the `man`s (I tried that already myself prior to asking here) about the location of record/bookkeeping regarding the time/date of installation / removal of packages. Then it seems its only in the `/var/log/dpkg.log.*` files. That is fine I guess. Just a pitty if they ever get lost